# How to render an object of arrays with useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I can't seem to get my object of arrays working. I want to pass an array from an api into a setstate function to turn that state into an array. Then iterate over that array. iterating should give me access to the object's properties. I want to access unique object properties to return and render them into my component. However, I get an error "Object Expected".

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { CharacterComponent } from "../src/CharacterComponent"
import axios from "axios"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export const Characters = () => {
  // Try to think through what state you'll need for this app before starting. Then build out
  // the state properties here.

  // Fetch characters from the star wars api in an effect hook. Remember, anytime you have a 
  // side effect in a component, you want to think about which state and/or props it should
  // sync up with, if any.
  const [character,setCharacter] = useState({})
  useEffect( () => {
    axios.get("https://swapi.co/api/people")
    .then(res => setCharacter(res.data.results) )
  },[])

(console.log(character))
  return (
    <>
    <div>
    {character.map((element,index) => <CharacterComponent id={element} key={index} />)}
    </div>
    </>
  )


}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's weird, seems to be working fine in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-brook-veo3f

I initialized the state as an empty array as well:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import CharacterComponent from "./CharacterComponent";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [character, setCharacter] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://swapi.co/api/people")
      .then(res => setCharacter(res.data.results));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {character.map(item => (
        <CharacterComponent id={item} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Maybe take a look to see if there's something wrong with your child component:

```
import React from "react";

const CharacterComponent = ({ id }) => {
  return <div>{id.name}</div>;
};

export default CharacterComponent;
```

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code in I have no idea why this isn't working I'm going to ask my instructor what's up thanks for trying though man.

Comment: @tgmarcus are you using create-react-app? Also you need React 16.8 at the minimum to run hooks.